# Errors in relative path

Tags: c++, file, directory, file-handling

So this is a simple C++ program for reading a file and displaying its contents.
My directory structure is as follows

```
Project Directory
|
Data___
|      |
|      data.txt
|
program1.cpp
```

and The program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    char char1;

    fstream data; // Because I wanna to write to this file later.
    data.open("../Data/data.txt",ios::out | ios::in);

    if (data.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; !data.eof(); ++i) {
            data.get(char1);
            cout << char1 << endl;
        }
        data.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So currently my program works fine... However when I use:

```
data.open("Data/data.txt",ios::out | ios::in);
```

The program doesn't work. Why is this so? Ideally the above mentioned code piece should work since the **Data** folder is in the same directory as my cpp file.

```
data.open("../Data/data.txt",ios::out | ios::in);
```

By using 2 dots we are going back a directory and the Data folder isn't there.

Then why is the program working using the 2 dots?

Comment: Pathnames are interpreted relative to your current directory, not the directory containing the program.

Comment: Where your cpp file is has nothing to do with where the search starts. The current directory of your executable is where the seach begins.

Comment: Got it... turns out my executable was located in a different folder in the project directory itself... Thanks! @Barmar and Mike

Comment: Regarding `for (int i = 0; !data.eof(); ++i)`, give [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) a read. It can save you some future debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your directory structure, I see that both your program1.cpp and data.txt are in the same "Data" folder. Since you are already inside the Data folder, "Data/data.txt" looks for another Data folder. In UNIX ".." means the previous directory. So when you use ".." you go to "Project Directory", which contains a "Data" folder. That is why data.open("../Data/data.txt",ios::out | ios::in) is working. You can also try using the following:
`data.open("data.txt",ios::out | ios::in);`